# Using iPhone coordinates with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, android, ios

I'm working on a Leaflet map using Chrome on a PC and everything works fine when I use my computer or Android phone.

[image: Correct coordinates]

But when viewed in Chrome on an iPhone, the coordinates get shifted, like below.

[image: shift in Chrome on iPhone].

Is there any quick way to convert those coordinates for my bounds and geoJSONs to ones an iPhone would correctly recognize?

Otherwise, I think I'll just have to somehow use a Mac and completely shift over everything and have a separate site just for iPhone users.

Editing to add the script plus one of the geoJSONs below (using Leaflet 1.8.0):

```
    <script>
      //add Mapbox tilelayers
      var sat = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/" target="_blank">Improve this map</a></strong>',
        tileSize: 512,
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        id: 'mapbox.satellite',
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW1hZ3VpZ2EiLCJhIjoiY2xiMmMyemsyMDA5czNwcnBhZDFiaWcyeCJ9.TzzxHt4q9OIY6wJn5AzJdw'
      });

      var streets = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/">Mapbox</a> <strong><a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/" target="_blank">Improve this map</a></strong>',
        tileSize: 512,
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW1hZ3VpZ2EiLCJhIjoiY2xiMmMyemsyMDA5czNwcnBhZDFiaWcyeCJ9.TzzxHt4q9OIY6wJn5AzJdw'
      });

      //create map centered on campus
      var map = L.map('map', {
        layers: [streets]
      });

      var baseMaps = {
        "Streets": streets,
        "Satellite": sat
      };

      var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, null, {
        collapsed: false
      }).addTo(map);

      var tl = L.latLng(32.432728835176244, -93.70493399036371)
      var br = L.latLng(32.425335441464614, -93.69897141723949)
      var bounds = L.latLngBounds(tl, br);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

      //create pane for background, set zIndex
      map.createPane('back');
      map.getPane('back').style.zIndex = 200;

      //add img for building names, no labeling system works well for Leaflet
      var labels = 'Labels.PNG';
      var labelbounds = [
        [32.43260220802694, -93.71002106489411],
        [32.425486730263934, -93.69809346693055]
      ];
      L.imageOverlay(labels, labelbounds, {
        zIndex: 300
      }).addTo(map);

      //create geoJSONs for polygons to go on the map
      var abgeoJSON = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [-93.70653055608273, 32.42667183737912],
              [-93.70647020637989, 32.42656542956566],
              [-93.70643332600594, 32.42657844754959],
              [-93.70635688304901, 32.42644826762586],
              [-93.70616912841797, 32.42652467760386],
              [-93.70615303516387, 32.42649524561999],
              [-93.7060672044754, 32.42652863960095],
              [-93.70614632964134, 32.4266661773922],
              [-93.70607726275921, 32.42683824083571],
              [-93.70591029524802, 32.42690729252007],
              [-93.70595052838326, 32.42697747614509],
              [-93.70599411427975, 32.42696049624081],
              [-93.7061195075512, 32.427180102756026],
              [-93.70623148977757, 32.427137653084735],
              [-93.70625026524067, 32.42716538687225],
              [-93.70641052722931, 32.42709973136147],
              [-93.70629787445068, 32.426902198545164],
              [-93.70636358857155, 32.4267397571944],
              [-93.70653055608273, 32.42667183737912]
            ]
          ]
        }
      };
 //create polygons from the geoJSONS above
      L.geoJSON(abgeoJSON, {
        'fillcolor': '#FDD023',
        'fillopacity': 1.0,
        'color': '#FDD023',
        'opacity': 1
      }).bindPopup("<h4>Administration<br> Building</h4><h6>______________________</h6><br><a href='https://youtu.be/2FMMqT8VqSI?t=242'  target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'><img src= 'AB.PNG' alt='Administration Building Front'</a><br><a href='https://www.lsus.edu/why-lsus/lsus-leadership-team' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>Chancellor's Office</a> <br><a href='https://www.lsus.edu/academics/academic-affairs' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>Academic Affairs</a> <br><a href='https://www.lsus.edu/academics/graduate-studies' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>Graduate Studies</a> <br><a href='https://www.lsus.edu/current-students/dean-of-students' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>Dean of Students</a><br><a href='https://www.lsus.edu/current-students/accounting-services' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>Accounting Services</a><br><a href='https://www.lsus.edu/costs-and-aid' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>Financial Aid</a> <br><p>and more</p>").addTo(map);
```

Comment: What browsers are you using to view the map? Have you tried Chrome on the iPhone? I am not sure its a coordinate issue.

Comment: Without seeing relevant part of your code it's impossible to give any advice/solution. Please edit your question, add relevant part of the code and sample of data.

Comment: Please also include information about the size (both in CSS pixels and device pixels) of the map canvas in both cases.

Comment: @KeaganAllan If you read, the screenshot comes from Chrome on iPhone. It also happens with Safari on iPhone. It works perfectly in Chrome and Edge on PC and Android.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I'm not sure the device pixels for the map canvas, but I put it in percentage so I would avoid the issues of switching from computer to mobile device.

Comment: @TomazicM I added code and one of the building geoJSONs